# Replace String in HTML With Certain Characteristics

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I need to replace every instance of a an `img` tag that starts with `http://player.vimeo.com` with another url.

For example, you might find this in the code of the page:

```
<img src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/4887233">
```

I'm trying to make a jQuery script that will find every `img` src that begins with `http://player.vimeo.com` and replace the `src` with another string (it will be the same string for every vimeo link, essentially one variable).

How do I find the vimeo links and make sure the entire link is replaced no matter the length (some links will be longer than others but will always start with the same string)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select all the `img` with an [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("img[src^='http://player.vimeo.com]'").each(function(){
    this.src = this.src.replace("player.vimeo.com", "new.url.com");
});
```

The above will replace `player.vimeo.com` in the `src` with `new.url.com`. If you need to set another `src` altogether, just do `this.src = 'new url';`.

It's worth noting that when you want to change native attributes such as `src`, `each` will perform much better compared to `attr`, as can be seen in this [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/attr-vs-each).

Check out [demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7524T/3/).

Comment: Looks great. Is there a way to tell the script to start once the page has ben completely loaded?

Comment: Sure, just add it to a [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event callback: `$(function(){ /* Add the above code in here */ });`

Comment: @DannyCooper Added a link to a fiddle that demonstrates the basic usage.

Comment: Hi Marcus, works well except is there a way to replace the entire URL instead of just the first part? So in your example the foo/bar/1337 would all be replaced as well no matter how long that string is.

Comment: @DannyCooper I did add that to my answer, replace the second line with  `this.src = 'new url';`

Comment: This is only replacing the "player.vimeo.com" part, how do I replace the entire url?

Comment: @DannyCooper I see you figured it out ;) thanks for accepting my answer and updating the fiddle!

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
$("img[src^=\"http://player.vimeo.com\"]").attr("src", "new_string")
```

or

```
$("img[src^=\"http://player.vimeo.com\"]").attr("src", function(i, val) {return val.replace("http://player.vimeo.com", "new url")})
```

Not enough clear from a question if it should replace whole link or just 'http://player...' with some another string, so code for both cases.

According to [Markus Ekwall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624625/replace-string-in-html-with-certain-characteristics/13624713#comment-18685344) comment, attr is slower than each, so it would be better to replace code above with:

```
$("img[src^=\"http://player.vimeo.com\"]").each(function() {this.src = "new_string";});
```

or

```
$("img[src^=\"http://player.vimeo.com\"]").each(function() { this.src = this.src.replace("http://player.vimeo.com", "new url"); })
```

Comment: +1 this is better than filter if you don’t need to do regex matching.

Comment: `attr` is very slow (~90% slower) compared to `each` as can be seen here: http://jsperf.com/attr-vs-each

Comment: @MarcusEkwall Thank! Really interesting moment which I had no idea about.

Comment: @FAngel That's one of the major issues with jQuery and the likes. If you don't really know what's going on behind the curtains, you can easily create very non-performant code ;)

Comment: @MarcusEkwall Frankly speaking, I would never expect `.attr` to be SO slow. Thanks againg for sharing your experience. You have my +1 where it was possible ;)

Comment: @FAngel The magic going on inside `attr` creates a massive overhead that isn't needed for native attributes. The same goes when you want to access attributes as well. Whenever you can, you should use native get/set.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall I know that, suppose, each jquery function will have some overhead comparing to native methods. Just for that exact method I did not expect so mach overhead. Well... that is a price for cross-browser compatibility and other usefull things jQuery provides to us.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a `filter()` on each element and match the `src` attribute, then replace it:

```
$('img').filter(function() {
    return /^http:\/\/player\.vimeo\.com/.test(this.src);
}).attr('src', 'somethingelse');
```

You can also use a function instead of 'somethingelse'  if you want to do individual replacements, f.ex:

```
.attr('src', function(i, src) {
    return src.replace(/vimeo/,'youtube');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Access the href attribute of an element using it id and pass your updated href string url to the attr method:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    $("#link").attr("href","http://www.example.com/login.html"); //pass ur new url here
  });
});
 </script>
```

inside the html body:

```
<p><a href="http://www.example.com" id="link">Link name</a></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this if you only want to replace the search-url.

```
$(function(){
    $('img').each(function(index,elem) {
        var newValue = "http://youtube.com";

        var $this = $(this);
        var strSrc = $this.attr('src');
        var regTest = /http:\/\/player\.vimeo\.com/;

        if(regTest.test(strSrc)) {
            $this.attr('src', strSrc.replace(regTest, newValue) );
        }
    });
});
```